# Multiple insert into in SQL Developer worksheet

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I just installed `SQL Developer 4` and I'm using `Oracle Database 11g`. I want to execute multiple insert into statements in the worksheet at once. That works fine if I copy paste via command line of SQL but in Develop 4, only one row is being inserted at a time. Is there any way to fix this? I don't want to type line by line and also don't want directly enter via data tab though the textboxes. I want be able to execute the following in one single worksheet. Please help

```
INSERT INTO client_master(client_no,name,city,pincode,state,bal_due) VALUES ('c00001','ivan bayross','bombay',400054,'maharashtra',15000);
INSERT INTO client_master(client_no,name,city,pincode,state,bal_due) VALUES ('c00002','vandana saitwal','madras',780001,'tamil nadu',0);
INSERT INTO client_master(client_no,name,city,pincode,state,bal_due) VALUES ('c00003','pramada jaguste','bombay',400057,'maharashtra',5000);
INSERT INTO client_master(client_no,name,city,pincode,state,bal_due) VALUES ('c00004','basu navindgi','bombay',400056,'maharashtra',0);
INSERT INTO client_master(client_no,name,city,pincode,state,bal_due) VALUES ('c00005','ravi sreedharan','delhi',100001,'delhi',2000);
INSERT INTO client_master(client_no,name,city,pincode,state,bal_due) VALUES ('c00006','rukmini','bombay',400057,'maharashtra',0);
```

Comment: Are you doing 'run statement' (ctrl-enter, or the green 'play' button); or 'run script' (F5, or the smaller green 'play' button on top of a doc icon)?

Comment: WOW! Thanks a lot! That explains it. I have be using run statement!

Answer (score 4):

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35137_01/appdev.32/e35117/intro.htm#CHDDHAAI) (3.2 since 4 is still beta):

> **SQL Worksheet toolbar** (under the Worksheet tab): Contains icons for the following operations:
>
> **Execute Statement** executes the statement at the mouse pointer in the
>   Enter SQL Statement box. The SQL statements can include bind variables
>   and substitution variables of type VARCHAR2 (although in most cases,
>   VARCHAR2 is automatically converted internally to NUMBER if
>   necessary); a pop-up box is displayed for entering variable values.
>
> **Run Script** executes all statements in the Enter SQL Statement box
>   using the Script Runner. The SQL statements can include substitution
>   variables (but not bind variables) of type VARCHAR2 (although in most
>   cases, VARCHAR2 is automatically converted internally to NUMBER if
>   necessary); a pop-up box is displayed for entering substitution
>   variable values.

To run multiple statements together you need to Run Script, either from the toolbar icon or by pressing F5.

Answer (score 1):

After all of the insert statements are in the "Query" Builder window, you can "hilight" (Control A) and then hit "Control" and "Enter" at the same time.